# jQuery - list input classess and get number of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for jQuery code which will list all classess from inputs and display how many times every class (in this case class=value) is selected.

html schema:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="t1" class="a1" value="a1">
<input type="checkbox" name="t1" class="a2" value="a2">
<input type="checkbox" name="t1" class="a3" value="a3">
<input type="checkbox" name="t2" class="a1" value="a1">
<input type="checkbox" name="t2" class="a2" value="a2">
<input type="checkbox" name="t2" class="a3" value="a3">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="t9" class="a99" value="a99">
```

example of expected result:

```
a1 - 2
a2 - 0
a3 - 0
a99 - 0
```

Comment: Well, nobody singing "What have you tried so far?" ♪♫

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var map = {};
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        map[this.className] = (map[this.className] || 0) + 1;
    } else {
        map[this.className] = map[this.className] || 0;
    }
});
console.log(map)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CU7AK/)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smBSw/1/

```
var resultList = {}

$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    var result = resultList[this.className] || 0;

    if (this.checked) {
        result++;
    }

    resultList[this.className] = result;
});

console.log(resultList)
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var checked = new Array();

$("input[type=checkbox]").each( function() {
  var cl = $(this).attr('class');
  if (typeof(checked[cl]) == "undefined") checked[cl] = 0;
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) checked[cl]++;
});
```

After this, you will have variable `checked` containing all checkbox classes, with number of checked boxes for each class.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like :

```
var className = [];
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#result").html("");
    $("input[class^=a]").each(function () {
        className.push($(this).attr("class"));
    });
    className = jQuery.unique(className);
    for (i = 0; i < className.length; i++) {
        var count = 0;
        $("." + className[i]).each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        $("#result").append(
            "<br/><span> " +
                "className: " + className[i] + ", " +
                "count :" + count + 
            "</span>"
        );
    }
});
```

demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4W5ND/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Basically you will need to iterate through these inputs.. but you will need a place to save the counts

```
$(".checkboxes").on("change", "input", function() {
var results = {"a1": 0, "a2": 0, "a3": 0};

$(".checkboxes input").each(function(i, checkbox) {
    if (!$(checkbox).prop("checked")) {
        return;
    }

    results[$(checkbox).val()] =  results[$(checkbox).val()] + 1;
});

var resultsToAppend = '';

$.each(results, function(key, value) {
    resultsToAppend += '<li>' + key + ' : ' + value + '</li>';
});

$(".results").html(resultsToAppend);
```

});

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rDt9/1/)

Comment: Please note that you can build the results map dynamically as well.. so it wont need initialization..

Comment: At least the one who down-voted should clarify why the down-vote?

Comment: These one looks nice, thank you. How to build result map on page load? Number of classes may vary, so creating static array won't work

Comment: It can be done dynamic easily.. and if you wanna do it on page load then use: $(document).ready(function() { /*PLACE THE CODE HERE */ });

Comment: Here's a modified fiddle that does it on page load and works dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/9rDt9/2/